# значение слова "юлить" в данном предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли я понял, что в данном случае слово "юлить" употреблено в значении "лгать":"Я всю свою молодость тебе юлил, чтобы получить выгоду"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понимать это предложение — затея не из лучших: слово "юлить" в нём согласовано неправильно. Какой бы смысл не заложил автор, он должен был написать "перед/с тобой юлил", а не "тебе".
Слово не имеет значения "лгать". "Лгать" —  это говорить неправду. Юлящий человек не врёт, а просто старается не сказать то, что ему не выгодно. Он изворачивается. Также есть значение "юлить"  — лебезить, заискивать.